# Enabling Mysql 5.6 UTF-8 Encoding, Glassfish 3.1.2.2, EJB3

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I've been trying to set UTF-8 encoding for my application. Currently, it is set to default latin1. I've gone through a couple of blogs and made the requisite changes on the JSP, glassfish-web.xml and mysql as suggested in them. I tried to test the encoding by creating a test table with latin1 and then converting it to utf8. I've made the following changes:

Database table:

```
select * from test_latin;
+-------+
| c     |
+-------+
| a     |
| abc   |
| ©     |
| Á     |
| ß ö   |
+-------+

select * from test_utf8;
+-------+
| c     |
+-------+
| a     |
| abc   |
| ©     |
| Á     |
| ß ö   |
+-------+
```

Added this to web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>utf8EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>gji.web.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>utf8EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In the jsps:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

In the java code, I can see them printed correctly in logs. But on the JSP it shows as:

```
Info: utf-8 char:- a
Info: utf-8 char:- abc
Info: utf-8 char:- ©
Info: utf-8 char:- Á
Info: utf-8 char:- ß ö
Info: latin char:- a
Info: latin char:- abc
Info: latin char:- ©
Info: latin char:- Á
Info: latin char:- ß ö

LATIN:[a, abc, ￯﾿ﾂ￯ﾾﾩ, ￯﾿ﾃ￯ﾾﾁ, ￯﾿ﾃ￯ﾾﾟ ￯﾿ﾃ￯ﾾﾶ] 
UTF-8:[a, abc, ￯﾿ﾂ￯ﾾﾩ, ￯﾿ﾃ￯ﾾﾁ, ￯﾿ﾃ￯ﾾﾟ ￯﾿ﾃ￯ﾾﾶ]
```

In the glassfish config, I've added the settings to enable utf-8 encoding. Similarly added the parameter for the database connection.

Using the code from an answer on stackoverflow, I added a filter to print response output. The response output prints the following:

```
<label>LATIN:</label>[a, abc, ￯﾿ﾂ￯ﾾﾩ, ￯﾿ﾃ￯ﾾﾁ, ￯﾿ﾃ￯ﾾﾟ ￯﾿ﾃ￯ﾾﾶ]

<label>UTF-8:</label>[a, abc, ￯﾿ﾂ￯ﾾﾩ, ￯﾿ﾃ￯ﾾﾁ, ￯﾿ﾃ￯ﾾﾟ ￯﾿ﾃ￯ﾾﾶ]
```

Hex values and char variable values:

```
mysql> select c,length(c),char_length(c),charset(c), hex(c) from   test_latin;
+-------+-----------+----------------+------------+--------+
| c     | length(c) | char_length(c) | charset(c) | hex(c) |
+-------+-----------+----------------+------------+--------+
| a     |         1 |              1 | latin1     | 61     |
| abc   |         3 |              3 | latin1     | 616263 |
| ©     |         1 |              1 | latin1     | A9     |
| Á     |         1 |              1 | latin1     | C1     |
| ß ö   |         3 |              3 | latin1     | DF20F6 |
+-------+-----------+----------------+------------+--------+

mysql> select c,length(c),char_length(c),charset(c), hex(c) from test_utf8;
+-------+-----------+----------------+------------+------------+
| c     | length(c) | char_length(c) | charset(c) | hex(c)     |
+-------+-----------+----------------+------------+------------+
| a     |         1 |              1 | utf8       | 61         |
| abc   |         3 |              3 | utf8       | 616263     |
| ©     |         2 |              1 | utf8       | C2A9       |
| Á     |         2 |              1 | utf8       | C381       |
| ß ö   |         5 |              3 | utf8       | C39F20C3B6 |
+-------+-----------+----------------+------------+------------+

mysql> show variables like '%char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

I'm stuck with this. Your guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please do `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...` for each table, perhaps for the copyright symbol line.  I don't yet see how it could become FFEF...

Comment: @RickJames please check the summary with the output of the tables with hex values.

Comment: Those hex values look as they should.  Any clue where `￯﾿ﾂ￯ﾾﾩ` is coming from?